# Надо избавится от нуля справа

Tags: python

Ввожу `input=150`

```
a=int(input())
b=a//60
c=a/5
'{:0}'.format(c)
print(a, 'мин - это' ,b, 'час' ,c, 'минут.')
```

> 150 мин - это 2 час 30.0 минут

Как избавится от дробной части минут?

Comment: справа где? в минутах ваших? вы, кстати, их неправильно считаете.

Comment: Да в минутах мне тоже сказали что я не правильно считаю а как тогда считать???

Comment: `print(f'{a} мин - это, {b} час, {c:.0f} минут.')`

Comment: `hr, mn = divmod(a, 60)`

Comment: Не совсем понял это надо добавить туда же???

Comment: @Егор, [так, надеюсь, понятнее ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1153962/211923)

Comment: Да,спасибо!!! Теперь понял

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = int(input())
hr, mn = divmod(a, 60)
print(f'{a} мин - это, {hr} час, {mn} минут.')
```

---

вывод:

```
150 мин - это, 2 час, 30 минут.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=150
b=a//60
c=a-b*60
print(a, 'мин - это' ,b, 'час' ,c, 'минут.')
```

> 150 мин - это 2 час 30 минут.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых вы неправильно считаете минуты и из-за этого они получаются в формате `float`, а значит с 0 на конце.

```
c=a%60
```

Итого:

```
a=int(input())
b=a//60
c=a%60

print(a, 'мин - это' ,b, 'час' ,c, 'минут.')
```